# BDC Lightning tool on MOSS 2007. Using BDC in Picker and filtering

Tags: filter, list-form, bdc-model, custom-bdc

I've got a BDC I generated with BDC Lightning BDC Man.  I added a BDC column to a list and when I open the address book picker I get the first 200 entries but search/filter does not work.

Anybody know how to implement it so that search filters as a wildcard so that all rows where the column has a match of the entered column are filtered?  For example, if I enter **"tea"** it returns following departments:

```
Tea
Team 1
Cup of tea for you.
```

It's a simple table with a list of departments and an Id column key.

```
 <Entity EstimatedInstanceCount="0" Name="dbo.UMDepartments">
  <Identifiers>
    <Identifier TypeName="System.Int32" Name="[id]" />
  </Identifiers>
  <Methods>
    <Method Name="Getdbo.[UMDepartments]">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="RdbCommandText" Type="System.String">Select [id],[Department] From dbo.[UMDepartments]</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbCommandType" Type="System.Data.CommandType">Text</Property>
      </Properties>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]">
          <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataReader, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IsCollection="true" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]DataReader">
            <TypeDescriptors>
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataRecord, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]DataRecord">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Int32" Name="id" IdentifierName="[id]" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Department">
                    <Properties>
                      <Property Name="ShowInPicker" Type="System.Boolean">true</Property>
                    </Properties>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </TypeDescriptors>
          </TypeDescriptor>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
      <MethodInstances>
        <MethodInstance Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]Finder" Type="Finder" ReturnParameterName="dbo.[UMDepartments]" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="dbo.[UMDepartments]DataReader" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0" />
      </MethodInstances>
    </Method>
    <Method Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]SpecificFinder">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="RdbCommandText" Type="System.String">Select [id],[Department] From dbo.[UMDepartments] Where ([id]=@id)</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbCommandType" Type="System.Data.CommandType">Text</Property>
      </Properties>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Direction="In" Name="@id">
          <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Int32" Name="[id]" IdentifierName="[id]" />
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]">
          <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataReader, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IsCollection="true" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]DataReader">
            <TypeDescriptors>
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataRecord, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]DataRecord">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Int32" Name="id" IdentifierName="[id]" />
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" Name="Department" />
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </TypeDescriptors>
          </TypeDescriptor>
        </Parameter>
      </Parameters>
      <MethodInstances>
        <MethodInstance Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]SpecificFinder" Type="SpecificFinder" ReturnParameterName="dbo.[UMDepartments]" ReturnTypeDescriptorName="dbo.[UMDepartments]DataReader" ReturnTypeDescriptorLevel="0" />
      </MethodInstances>
    </Method>
    <Method Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]IdEnumerator">
      <Properties>
        <Property Name="RdbCommandText" Type="System.String">Select [id] From dbo.[UMDepartments]</Property>
        <Property Name="RdbCommandType" Type="System.Data.CommandType">Text</Property>
      </Properties>
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]IDs">
          <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataReader, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" IsCollection="true" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]IDs">
            <TypeDescriptors>
              <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Data.IDataRecord, System.Data, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Name="dbo.[UMDepartments]">
                <TypeDescriptors>
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Int32" Name="id" IdentifierName="[id]" />
                </TypeDescriptors>
              </TypeDescriptor>
            </TypeDescriptors>
          </TypeDescriptor>
        </Parameter
```

Comment: To those voting to close I don't think it should be. The use of the BDC meta man tool to generate this is incidental - the question is about BDC. In much the same way that a question about CAML that happened to be generated with U2U's caml query tool is still a q about caml.